# Passing value of an input control to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following:

```
@Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Shared", new { guid = Model.VideoGuid, content="", userid = authenticatedUserId.ToString()}){
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="txtCommentContent" type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">
                            <img src="~/Content/images/Message-Add.png" /></button>
                    </span>
                </div>

            }
```

I need to pass the text input inside the input control to the control as part of the routeValues. The above content="" is going to do that.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `HTML Helpers`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CommentContent);
```

This will model bind the value in `CommentContent` (Which should be a property in your model) and pass it back up to the server when the form is `POSTED`.

As an alternative solution, you can also serialize the form and pass it up via `AJAX`.

As @Ic has pointed out you could also use:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommentContent, new { @class = "form-control" });
```

Which will change the input type to `text` and also add your `CSS` class `form-control`.

Comment: Or, more accurately in this case `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommentContent, new {@class="form-control"})` since the OP wants to specify a class, unless the template already has said class built-in.

Comment: @Ic - yeah sure. I'll include that in my post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Darren, the model I use within the view doesn't contain a direct reference to comments, they are loosely bound within the db models. A comment has a guid element and type member which I filter out when looking for comments for a given object. In that case, how can I access the content of the control if it's not part of my model passed to the view I'm in?

Comment: @driverobject - either include the definition in your Model or serialize the form and pass the data back up to the server in an AJAX call.